# Launch program on server through web

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

OK, so I'm in a strange development situation and am a noob at the bits I'm tasked with - just to make life fun and interesting.

My fellow developer has written programs in VB.Net and placed them on the server.  He wants a web front end that users can click a link and have that run the program on the server.

Sounds simple, but I've spent days searching the internet and found only two solutions one of which looks sketchy on security and the other is so complex I'm not sure how to make it fit my local variables.

I'm writing ASP.Net on an MVC Framework using C#.

So, in terms for the simple minded to understand, is there a way to do this?  Are there links which I used the wrong keywords and completely missed?  Or even a suggestion on which tech docs to look at to try and track this down.

Comment: This sounds like a security nightmare

Answer (score 1):

I would have your fellow developer convert his application to a library that you can reference in your c#.. Doing what you want to do does not sound like a good idea at all and I would avoid it at almost all cost.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar requirements.

How I handled it: write another program that runs in memory on the server and is looking at my database (or file system) on a schedule. The ID of the application to run is then added to the DB/Filesystem from the web page; during the next scheduled check (mine checks every 5 seconds) any scheduled applications are run.

It isn't a direct execution, but gets the job done and is very straightforward.

FYI: My requirement was to do some office automation task.